# Drag&Drop>> e.getData return null

Tags: c#

i am trying to use drag drop in c#,but something strange happened and i dont why,these are codes that i am

```js
        void imageRenderer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {                                
                imageRenderer.DoDragDrop(new DragData("Helloo",dropImage), DragDropEffects.All);
        }
```

this is my DragData class that store 1 string and 1 image:

```js
    class DragData {
        public string plantName;
        public Image dragImage;

        public DragData(string name,Image dragingImage) {
            name = plantName;
            dragImage = dragingImage;
        }
    }
```

and my problem is in dragEnter event:

```js
        void Tile_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
                DragData dropedData = (DragData)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragData));
                Image a= dropedData.dragImage; 
                string b=dropedData.plantName;
        }
```

Now,a is not null and works correct but b is null and i dont know why.thank u for your help.and how to fix it?:)

Comment: Change `name = plantName;` to `plantName = name;` in your `DragData` constructor.

Comment: thank u,i sorry for my mistake ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the member variable to the parameter:

```
public DragData(string name,Image dragingImage) { 
name = plantName;
```

Right way, assign the parameter to the member variable:

```
public DragData(string name,Image dragingImage) { 
plantName = name;
```

Comment: You're welcome. See the hollow tick (left of this under the up/down vote arrows), marking answers as correct let's everyone know your problem is solved and gives you a few rep points as well. Good luck!